# Problem with cancelling timer within a function (python)

Tags: python

I have a function constantly running in a loop checking if it should start or cancel a timer that's defined in the function's scope. Timer needs to be defined within the function as the callback is also defined in the function. I'm able to start the timer fine, but when it tries to cancel, I get an error 'local variable 'timer' referenced before assignment'.

I've tried defining the timer and its callback in the global scope (which is undesirable), and I get another error 'threads can only be started once'.

```
import threading
import random

def start():
    trigger = random.randint(0,1)
    def do_something():
        print(trigger)
    if trigger == 0:
        timer = threading.Timer(2,do_something)
        timer.start()
    else:
        timer.cancel() #: if trigger is 1, I want to cancel the timer
    threading.Timer(1,start).start() #: start() is in a loop and is constantly checking trigger's value

start()
```

I want the same timer to be started or cancelled according to trigger's value. timer and its callback should be defined within the function.

Comment: In the else case there is no timer.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, if I redefine timer in else:, it creates a new instance and doesn't cancel the previous timer which defeats the purpose of cancelling.

Comment: Your function looks to be recursive. That should mean that you will quickly run out of stack space.

Comment: What you are asking for is contradictory since, if you are looping somehow, it is likely that the timer will usually be cancelled before there is enough time for it to fire.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, irrelevant as in it's proper application that function is called when any button is pressed instead of calling itself. This code still recreates the same problem.

Comment: Good point, lets ignore the function calling itself for a second and focus on how to cancel the timer.

Comment: Edited, now start() is called after a second

Comment: It seems like the `timer` should be a global or an instance variable so that it can be found again once started. Let me see if I can come up with something that could possibly work.

Comment: Thank you in advance :D

Comment: **Since you need to store state, this cannot be a function** (`start()` ), it should be an instance with a data member `self.timer` which you store. Then you can define methods like `start(), stop()` etc. on that timer.

Answer (score 0):

This program shows how a random number can be used to start or stop a timer.

If the random number selects `0` enough times in a row, the timer will be started and be allowed to continue timing until time runs out and it calls its target.

If ever the random number selects `1`, the timer is cancelled and the target is not called:

```
import threading
import random
import time

class Timing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = None       # No timer at first
        self.something = None   # Nothing to print at first
        self.restart()

    def restart(self):
        self.run = threading.Timer(1.1, self.start)
        self.run.start()

    def cancel(self):
        if self.run is not None:
            self.run.cancel()
            self.run = None

    def start(self):
        trigger = random.randint(0, 1)
        self.do_start(trigger)

    def do_start(self, trigger):
        print('start', trigger)
        if trigger == 0:
            if self.timer is None:
                self.something = trigger
                self.timer = threading.Timer(2, self.do_something)
                self.timer.start()
        else:
            if self.timer is not None:
                self.timer.cancel()
                self.timer = None
                self.something=None
        self.restart()

    def do_something(self):
        print(self.something)

t = Timing()

print('sleeping...')
time.sleep(20)
t.cancel()
t.do_start(1)
t.cancel()
print('Done')
```

Sample output (ymmv because its random)

```
sleeping...
start 1
start 0
start 1
start 0
start 0
0
start 1
start 0
start 1
start 1
start 1
start 1
start 1
start 0
start 1
start 0
start 0
0
start 1
start 0
start 1
Done
```

Comment: Lengthy but seems to do the job! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've learnt from @quamrana and @smci and came up with this

```
import threading
import random

class Timer():
    pass
t = Timer()

def start():
    trigger = random.randint(0,1)
    def do_something():
        print(trigger)
    if trigger == 0:
        t.timer = threading.Timer(1,do_something)
        t.timer.start()
    else:
        if hasattr(t,'timer'):
            t.timer.cancel() 
    threading.Timer(1,start).start() 

start()
```

This seems to solve the issue while keeping the code compact.

Comment: Yes it seems to do what I wanted it to do, it cancels/starts the timer based on trigger value